# How to flatten a multi column dataframe into 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following table:

```py
group_a = {'ba':[2.0,9.4,10.8],
          'bb':[4.2,7.1,3],
          'bc':[8.1,9.5,6.1]}

A = pd.DataFrame(group_a, index=['aa','ab','ac'])
```

That looks like this:

```
    ba   bb   bc
aa  2.0  4.2  8.1
ab  9.4  7.1  9.5
ac  10.8 3.0  6.1
```

How can I flatten this table so that it looks like this:

```
       Values
aa_ba  2.0
aa_bb  4.2
aa_bc  8.1
ab_ba  9.4
ab_bb  7.1
ab_bc  9.5
ac_ba  10.8
ac_bb  3.0
ac_bc  6.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `stack` and rework the index:

```
B = A.stack()
B.index = B.index.map('_'.join)
out = B.to_frame('Values')
```

output:

```
       Values
aa_ba     2.0
aa_bb     4.2
aa_bc     8.1
ab_ba     9.4
ab_bb     7.1
ab_bc     9.5
ac_ba    10.8
ac_bb     3.0
ac_bc     6.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have your indexes set, you can do this most easily with a `.stack` operation. This results in a `pd.Series` with a `MultiIndex`, we can use a "_".join to join each level of the `MultiIndex` by an underscore and create a flat `Index`. Lastly, since you wanted a single column `DataFrame` you can use `.to_frame()` to convert the `Series` into a `DataFrame`

```py
out = A.stack()
out.index = out.index.map("_".join)
out = out.to_frame("values")

print(out)
       values
aa_ba     2.0
aa_bb     4.2
aa_bc     8.1
ab_ba     9.4
ab_bb     7.1
ab_bc     9.5
ac_ba    10.8
ac_bb     3.0
ac_bc     6.1
```

---

You can also use a method chained approach- just need to use `.pipe` to access the stacked index:

```py
out = (
    A.stack()
    .pipe(lambda s: s.set_axis(s.index.map("_".join)))
    .to_frame("values")
)

print(out)
       values
aa_ba     2.0
aa_bb     4.2
aa_bc     8.1
ab_ba     9.4
ab_bb     7.1
ab_bc     9.5
ac_ba    10.8
ac_bb     3.0
ac_bc     6.1
```

Comment: Very interesting solution with `.pipe`. It is more like R's pipe operator. I didn't know Python has such method as well. Thank you for your solution. It taught me a valuable lesson.

Answer (score 2):

Stack, use list comprehension and fstrings to compute new index .

```
 s = A.stack().to_frame('values')
    
 s.index=([f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in s.index])




        values
aa_ba     2.0
aa_bb     4.2
aa_bc     8.1
ab_ba     9.4
ab_bb     7.1
ab_bc     9.5
ac_ba    10.8
ac_bb     3.0
ac_bc     6.1
```